# Update procedure issue , Not getting the logic for status to get updated

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have one label(ie updated status comes in this label) and two dropdown list one is developer and another is tester.

When I assign both it is working fine and if am assigning/selecting only developer it is working fine . But when i select only tester individually without selecting any developer then the other issues label status also gets changed automatically if some other issues have different status for the timing it gets changed to status=2(ie , assigned ) .

I have used procedure

```
  ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_assignedto]
  (
   @employeeid int,
   @issuetrackerid int,
   @testerid int
  )
  as
  begin 
  update issuesdetails set assignedto=@employeeid,status =2 , testerassign=@testerid         where issuetrackerid=@issuetrackerid
  end
```

This status =2 is because if am selecting and assigning the status label should get updated to assigned .

Hope you got the issue.

Thanks

Comment: You must consider rephrasing the whole question into something understandable.

Comment: Can you post your c# code too to find the error?